# What kind of "IF" Statement in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, exception, model

What kind of IF statement to showing ALERT ..

```
function actAdd(){
    $this->load->model("person_model"); 
    $query = $this->person_model->actPerson();
    if($query == TRUE){
        redirect('person/');    
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Failed !! Person is Exist.')</script>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='".base_url()."person/'</script>";
    }
}
```

`if($query==TRUE){` not INSERT data because record exist or anything else, i want to show the ALERT message.

So please help to find out right statement or syntax of Codeigniter query.

*sorry for my bad english*

Comment: Add the code for your `actPerson()` function within the person_model.

Comment: if `$query` is there direct result of a database query, it will be `false` if there was an error, but it may be an object if there was no error. try `$query !== false` as your test.

Comment: its work, @Jerry !! I've add return in $query insert, and the alert showed. tanks alot.